# UIView child automatic frame size

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, snapkit

I am trying to add custom UIView (LabelIcon) to a parent view, that should not care about size of the child - he should just stack them with full width under each other based on the height of the child (which will vary).

Currently this is how I add a child in the parent:

```
    let locationLabel = LabelIcon(frame: .zero, icon: "location", text: "Lane\nlane")
    let locationLabel2 = LabelIcon(frame: .zero, icon: "location", text: "Second text line\nLine line line\nAnother line\nsome more line")
    content.addSubview(locationLabel)
    content.addSubview(locationLabel2)
```

(I don't want to set manually the frame here - should be automatic)

Constraints of these views so they are at least somehow visible (since I didn't set the frame):

```
    locationLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.left.right.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(40)
    }

    locationLabel2.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
        make.top.equalTo(locationLabel.snp.bottom)
        make.height.equalTo(40)
    }
```

This could work, but it would be painful to do this for each element. Also I don't know the height of inner element right now.

What I want to achieve is to not have to define any hardcoded constraints in parent. The child view should decide for himself how tall it will be.

The child is defined this way:

```
class LabelIcon: UIView {

    init(frame: CGRect, icon: String, text: String) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        let iconImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: icon))
        iconImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        self.addSubview(iconImageView)


        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = text
        self.addSubview(label)

        iconImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(5)
            make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
        }

        label.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.left.equalTo(iconImageView.snp.right).offset(20)

        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

How can I define child in a way that it is aware of parent's width, but height will be done automatically based on the label size? The text will have dynamic number of lines.

In parent there will be many views like this, therefore I want to have there as few constraints as possible (not to manually do it for every LabelIcon instance).

Based on this code this is the current state:
[image]

All my views are done programatically with autolayout (with SnapKit, no storyboard or xib). I would like to use UIStackView, but anyway the child has to have defined height in order for it to work.

**EDIT:**
Views itself are visible when using these constraints:

```
locationLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.left.right.equalToSuperview()

}
locationLabel2.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
    make.top.equalTo(locationLabel.snp.bottom)
}
```

Bu the views are over each other (label2 is not below label). Also the view is basically 0,0 in dimensions - there is no orange background:
[image]

**From accepted answer:**

Label constraints:

```
label.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.equalToSuperview()
    make.left.equalTo(iconImageView.snp.right).offset(20)
    make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-10)
    make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-10)
}
```

Parent:

```
locationLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.left.equalToSuperview()

}
locationLabel2.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.left.equalToSuperview()
    make.top.equalTo(locationLabel.snp.bottom)
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside label of the view add bottom constraint like this

```
 make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
```

//

Add right constraint

```
make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
```

remove any static height

```
make.height.equalTo(40)
```

then the view should resize according to text , the idea is to give the label a width by either a static value or a left&&right values

Comment: Updated:
label.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.left.equalTo(iconImageView.snp.right).offset(20)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-10)
            make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-10)
        }

And parent:
        locationLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.left.equalToSuperview()

        }
        locationLabel2.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.left.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalTo(locationLabel.snp.bottom)
        }
Thank you!